# If/Then Statement Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, background

```
    <title>Interactive Playground</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>


    <style>

         html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        position:relative;
        align-items: center;

        }


        .box1{
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            background-color: white;



        }


        .box2{
            height: 85%;
            width:90%;
            background-color: white;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;

        }

        .box3{
            height: 65%;
            width:80%;
            background-color: white;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
        }

        .box4{
            height: 45%;
            width:70%;
            background-color: white;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
        }

         .box5{
            height: 30%;
            width:60%;
            background-color: white;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
        }

        .box6{
            height: 15%;
            width:50%;
            background-color: white;
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
        }





    </style>

</head>

<body>


     <div id="box" class="box1"></div>

     <div id="box" class="box2"></div>

     <div id="box" class="box3"></div>

     <div id="box" class="box4"></div>

     <div id="box" class="box5"></div>

     <div id="box" class="box6"></div>




    <script>



        var clickCounts = 1;


            $('.box1').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#ffe1e1');
            });

            $('.box1').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

             $('.box2').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#ffd2d2');
            });

            $('.box2').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

            $('.box3').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#ffc3c3');
            });

            $('.box3').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

            $('.box4').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#ffb7b7');
            });

            $('.box4').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

             $('.box5').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#ff9d9d');
            });

            $('.box5').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

            $('.box6').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('background', '#e58d8d');
            });

            $('.box6').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            });

            $( ".box6" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');
                });

            $( ".box5" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');
                });

            $( ".box4" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');
                });

            $( ".box3" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');
                });

            $( ".box2" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');
                });

            $( ".box1" ).click(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'black');

                });
```

**I only need help getting started with writing if/then statements. Not looking for free work** I want to add an if/then statement to the bottom line of code so that when box 1 is clicked box 2 appears. This is to make the different shapes I have set up interact with one another.

I am not sure how to set up the syntax for if/then statements and I don't know if I need variables at the top of my script for that either? **thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as per the basic rule of html, every element must have unique ID. You can add same class to element but ID shouldn't be the same.

For getting started with if/else statement in Jquery please see below code, it is just simple if/else statement demonstrating how it works, you can explore it by your own way with the help of my implementation.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function()
  {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if(id == "box1")
    {
     $(".box2").addClass("appear").toggle();
    }
    else if(id == "box2")
    {
     $(".box3").addClass("appear").toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box
{
    border:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    height:20px;
     
}
.box1
{
 border:solid steelblue 2px;
}
.appear
{
   boder:solid blue 2px;
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="box1" class="box box1"></div>

  <div id="box2" class="box box2"></div>

  <div id="box3" class="box box3"></div>

  <div id="box4" class="box box4"></div>

  <div id="box5" class="box box5"></div>

  <div id="box6" class="box box6"></div>
</body>
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: That helps so much. Thank you for helping me with the html also!